# Should I post a new question?

Tags: discussion

I have posted a question today and got an answer. Then I thought of a new idea to make the code more helpful; should I post a new question with the corrected code from the other post to ask for help in that code to change the code function?

Comment: [That depends on your willingness to carry the associated burden of shame.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 10):

No, you shouldn't ask an SO question just because you got an idea and want someone to implement it for you.  Instead, spend some time attempting to implement the idea that you came up with yourself.  If, in the course of attempting to implement that idea you come across a problem that you are unable to solve, and doing research on that problem doesn't bring up existing solutions, then *that* is the time to consider posting an SO question with a description of what you're trying to do, what's actually happening, and how to reproduce that behavior.

Comment: No, that's *not* actually what you said.  You never said that you did any work on it, you never said that you were stuck, you never said that you didn't understand the meaning of anything.  Rather than insulting people with statements that are trivially proven false (by simply reading your own question) you should instead take the time to ensure that your question actually says all of the things that you need readers to understand (both in your meta questions, and your SO questions).

Comment: I said I need help with the code, NOT I need the code for my new idea.

Comment: @user3103193 You said that you need someone else to take the code that you have and change it to implement your new idea.  If you have actually implemented your new code, have a specific problem with it, and need help resolving *that*, then you should have said as much.  In your question you said none of that.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, but there is nothing in it to mean what you understood as well, so you should have asked, you said in the above comment "You said that you need someone else to take the code that you have and change it to implement your new idea." where in the post you found that I said I need someone to take my code and change it, Please copy it for me.

Comment: @user3103193 Your quesiton was clear, you were pretty explicit about what you were asking, hence why I didn't ask for clarification.  You just *clearly* asked for something that you apparently didn't want to ask about.  As far as the quote, here you go, "should I post a new question with the corrected code from the other post to ask for help in that code to change the code function?"

Comment: To ask for help, not for the code.

Comment: @user3103193 You asked for help "to change the code function", so yes, you asked for help *changing the code*.

Comment: I literally provided an exact quote from  your question.  Repeatedly claiming that you didn't say thing, *that are direct quotes from your question* is simply counter productive.  And no, this site isn't your own personal help desk that exists to serve your every need.  It's a site designed to create a useful repository of knowledge for all programmers.

Comment: @user3103193 also.... You shouldn't jump to calling people stupid or just using all caps... This is highly disrespectful to Servy. They were trying to help you. If they misunderstood something because your question was unclear, that's hardly their fault:/